# Automatically update the value in database column Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to update column status in table transaction automatically
but I got this error:

> **Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\TransactionController::updateconfirmed(), 0
>   passed and exactly 1 expected**

Here is the scenario:
1. User's status: hasn't payed
2. When I click button Confirmed, system send pusher notification to user that her/ his payment has been payed
3. Then my system return to confirmed.blade to give me a notif, then return to index, with status change to payed

This is my transaction blade:

```
@foreach($transactions as $transaction) 
                    <tr> 
                        <td>{{$transaction['id']}}</td> 
                        <td>{{$transaction['user_id']}}</td>
                        <td>{{$transaction['cara']}}</td>
                        <td>{{$transaction['start']}}</td>
                        <td>{{$transaction['end']}}</td>
                        <td>{{$transaction['total']}}</td>
                        <td><img src="fetch_image{{$transaction->id}}" class="img-thumbnail" width="75"/> </td>
                        <td>{{$transaction['status']}}</td> 
                        <td><a href="{{action('TransactionController@updateconfirmed', $transaction['id'])}}" class="btn btn-success">Konfirmasi</a></td>
```

This is my transaction controller:

```
public function updateconfirmed($id)
    {
        $transaction = Transaction::find($id);
        DB::update('update transactions set status = Lunas where id = ?', ['$id']);
        return view('confirmed');
    }
```

This is my confirmed.blade:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header" align="left">Confirmed</div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <p align="left">Event confirmed has been sent!</p>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <a href="{{Action('TransactionController@index')}}" class="btn btn-primary">Back</a>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This is my route:

```
Route::get('/confirmed', function () {
    event(new App\Events\StatusConfirmed('Admin'));
    return view('confirmed');
})->name('confirmed');

Route::get('/updateconfirmed', 'TransactionController@updateconfirmed');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
`Route::get('/updateconfirmed/{id}', 'TransactionController@updateconfirmed');`

The error because you are not passing the id(which one have to update) in your route

update: can try this also or Like other answer

```
       $transaction = Transaction::find($id);
       $transaction->update(['field_name' => value]);
       return view('confirmed');
```

Comment: wow thank youuu, but now I got this error:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Lunas' in 'field list' (SQL: update transactions set status = Lunas where id = $id)

Comment: Interesting username

Comment: @kerbholz will chnage it :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of DB::....$transaction->status = 'Lunas';$transaction->save() ;  or just put Lunas between ""